# How do researchers account for heterozygosity in genome assembly?

Tags: reference-genome, genome-sequencing

this is a very general question about diploid genome assembly. I am wondering how people deal with heterozygous region in a genome when assembling ?
Do they pick one of the haplotype to be in the referene and leave out the other ?
I am particularly thinking about situation similar to mammalian chromosome Y. 
Do you put Y or X in the assembly ? An hybrid ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally a single allele is used. This may be arbitrary or match the major allele frequency of the species. For sex chromosomes, usually both/all are included, so for mammals both X and Y are part of the reference genome.

Comment: In order to do so, do they perform "haplotype phasing" ? So, if you have something similar to sexual chromosome on another pair (really big divergent regions), one of them will be left out, as it is not recognise as a particular pair ?

Comment: There is usually nothing special done in this regard unless it's a more finished genome (mouse, human, etc.).